# Is it possible to find out which condition is being met in a multi condition if then statement?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a python/beautifulsoup web scraper. I'm searching for certain keywords, my statement looks like this:

```
if 'tribe' in entry or 'ai1ec' in entry or 'tfly' in entry:
            print('Plugin Found!')
            rating = easy
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=12).value = rating
```

What I would like to do is find out which one of those keywords is making the statement true. My first instinct would be to write a nested loop to check but I wasn't sure if there was a way to capture the value that makes the statement true that would involve less code?

Comment: Why nested loop? If there are only 3 keywords why not do some if, else if statements?

Comment: There are a lot more statements, this is the only one that contains multiple conditions. I'm just trying to make it more concise.

Comment: "which one of those keywords is making the statement true": what if there are more than 1 statement making it true?

Comment: In this instance, it should only be one in each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a generator comprehension that I would pass to `next` with a default value. If the comprehension doesn't find anything, `next` returns the default value, else it returns the first found and stops there (kind of `any`, but which stores the result)

```
cases = ['tribe','allec','tfly']
entry = 'iiii allec rrrr'


p = next((x for x in cases if x in entry),None)
if p is not None:
    print('Plugin Found!',p)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, the "Pythonic" way of doing it. The code I'm working with isn't making good use of pythons list comprehensions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT: changed to only find first name]

```
for name in ('tribe', 'ailec', 'tfly'):
    if name in entry:
        print ('Name =', name)
        print('Plugin Found!')
        rating = easy
        sheet.cell(row=i, column=12).value = rating
        break
```

Comment: you should break your loop or it doesn't stop at the first one found.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre: I assumed OP wants to print all names occurring in entry. After all, why should the first one matching be more important, since the order in the tuple or list seems arbitrary, not even on alphabet. Seemed illogical to me, although indeed that strictly is what OP asked.

Comment: fair enough. Asking clarification from OP

Comment: So,indeed, should have taken it literally, will make an edit.